# ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontr proceso especificado

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy usando una compilación propia de PyQt5 para Python 2.7 32bit, todo funciona bien desde la consola de Python.

El problema es cuando intento hacerlo funcionar dese el inteprete de Python integrado en kodi que QtWebkit quando intento importarlo me da el error `ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró proceso especificado` creo que tengo todas las dlls en su sitio.

Los demás módulos me funcionan bien QtCore, etc..

¿Hay alguna forma de saber CUAL es la DLL que está dando el problema?

Gracias

Comment: En mi caso tuve el error usando Anaconda. Con Azure Jupyter Notebook el error no se produce

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo arregle fijándome en `C:\Windows\System32 basicamente` el nombre de los `dll` que tenia instalado y vi que me los había instalado como `Qt5Core`. Le cambie el nombre y salio andando.