# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: No se encontró el proceso especificado

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

he intentando instalar Pyside2 en mi windows 10 de 64 bits he instala de la manera correcta e problema ocurre cuando deseo utilizar dicha libreria en mi editos de texto Anacond me arroja este error
**ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: No se encontró el proceso especificado.**

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QApplication
import sys

# Aplicación de Qt
app = QApplication()
# Se crea un botón con la palabra Hola
button = QPushButton('Hola')
# Se hace visible el botón
button.show()
# Qt loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo poco idea sobre el entorno que estas trabajando, lo que has intentado o la razón por la que cual se produce el error. Viendo en internet encontré varias posibles soluciones.

## Solucion 1

Echar un vistazo a C:\Windows\System32 y verificar los nombres de los dll´s que tienes instalados. Si estan diferentes, cambiar el nombre y listo. El dilema es saber cual dll esta dando el error.

[Referencia aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155225/importerror-dll-load-failed-no-se-encontr-proceso-especificado)

## Solucion 2

Tener actualizado el pip, por lo que la solucion es actualizar pip y reinstalar pyqt5

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install pyqt5
```

[Referencia aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331615/error-al-importar-pyqt5-en-python) y tambien [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287884/cant-download-pyqt5-on-python) y [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711301/install-pyqt5-5-14-1-on-linux)

## Solucion 3

> No estoy seguro de esta solución por que es para PyQt4 pero podrias intentar.

Reinstalar Python en modo administrador para todos los usuarios del pc, seleccionando "add to PATH" en el primer paso.
Abrir el command prompt en modo administrador y actualizar pip usando el comando `python -m pip install mitmproxy` (que saqué de este [linl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows) porque al tratar de correr `pip install --upgrade pip` arrojaba error de acceso denegado.
Después, bajar PyQt4 como .whl desde este [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4) fijándome que fuese la versión para Python 3.5.
Finalmente, instalar el .whl con pip install "archivo".whl desde la carpeta que lo contiene.

[Referencia aqui](https://github.com/IIC2233-2016-02/Syllabus/issues/204)

Si nada de esto funciona, tendrá que venir alguien con mas conocimiento en el tema para ayudarte;)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo tu ayuda fue de mucha utilidad , gracias por tu tiempo me has hecho una gran contribución ya que he podido solucionar el error.